# How to make a function print a value only on its first call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, printing, stateful

How do you get this function not to print the value `c` the second time it is called? I want this for my Hangman game.

Like this:

```
def myFunction(first,second,third):
   if first == True:
      # Do this
   elif second == True:
      c = third * 3

      print(c) # I do not want this to print on the second time it run
      return c

   else:
      print("Error")
```

Comment: IDLE will display it only if you run code in interactive mode. Just run the source code directly.

Comment: What do you mean by source code?

Comment: Not-printing something can be achieved by not calling print().

Comment: @PaulCornelius But I'm trying to say print only on first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorators can be used to change the behaviour of functions in such ways by making them stateful. Here, we can inject a `dict` argument with some state that the function can update and reuse through its lifetime.

```
def inject_state(state):

    def wrapper(f):

        def inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(state, *args, **kwargs)

        return inner_wrapper

    return wrapper


@inject_state({'print': True})
def myFunction(state, first, second, third):
   if first == True:
       pass # Do this
   elif second == True:
      c = third * 3

      # We print provided 'print' is True in our state
      if state['print']:
        print(c)

        # Once we printed, we do not want to print again
        state['print'] = False

      return c
   else:
      print("Error")
```

Here you see that the second call indeed does not print anything.

```
myFunction(False, True, 1) # 3
# prints: 3

myFunction(False, True, 1) # 3
# prints nothing
```

Comment: Wow! This code does work but the size is really big. But that is good enough . @OliverMelancon thanks!

Comment: It's really just because I made things sparse for readability. All I added is really just 9 lines and a quick example.

Comment: @Andrew By the way when you encounter helpful answers on StackOverflow, do not hesitate to upvote and accept them so other users can find them more easily. I see you have not been doing this in the past. It improves the site search quality and it gives you some good reputation.

Comment: @Oliver my reputation < 15 so yeah.